# Написал функцию, которая заменяет элементы строки, через forEach и явно объявленный массив - все ок. Почему через map, возвращает 2 массива?

Tags: javascript

```js
let str = 'abc def def lom abc abc def';

function replaceAll(find, replace, str) {
  let array = str.split(' ');
  array.map(element => {
    element === find ? array.push(replace) : array.push(element);
  });
  return array
};

console.log(replaceAll('abc', 'x', str));
```

Comment: ну а догадаться? array - где УЖЕ есть элементы и array куда происходит push. Это одна и та же переменная

Answer (score 2):

Строка:

```
let array = str.split(' ');
```

В `array` будет лежать массив элементов.

Далее:

```
array.push(...
```

тут заносим элементы в переменную array, которая **УЖЕ** существует, которая объявлена строкой выше и в которой **УЖЕ** существуют данные.

---

Если вам надо поменять что-то, то вам надо в элементе (`element`) менять, а не делать `push`. И возвращать результат работы `map`

И ещё одна ошибка: Если в стрелочной функции имеется тело или оборачивается в фигурные скобки, то надо принудительно писать `return` иначе функция внутри `map` ничего не вернёт...точнее вернёт сплошные `undefined`